# Distribute and assign items from one list to another

Tags: c#, list

I have a list of `Attackers` and `Targets`. I want each attacker to target at least 1 target.

If there are 4 Attackers and 4 Targets, then `Attacker[0]` would attack `Target[0]` and so on...

However if there are more attackers than the targets. For example

```
Attackers       Targets
Attacker[0]     Target[0]
Attacker[1]     Target[1]
Attacker[2]
```

Attacker[0] would attack Target[0], Attacker[1] would attack Target[1]. How would I make it that Attacker[2] would attack Target[0] again? Like it would just go back at the top of the list and iterate again for the remaining Attackers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a great use of modulus division. Take this psudo code:

```
target_index = attacker_index mod total_targets
```

Putting it into code

```cs
var totalTargets = 4; // get from your list length
var attackerIndex = 0; // get from some for loop
var targetIndex = attackerIndex % totalTargets;
```

Putting this into [a loop](https://dotnetfiddle.net/htsFU9) gives you:

```
Attacker 0 attacks 0
Attacker 1 attacks 1
Attacker 2 attacks 0
Attacker 3 attacks 1
Attacker 4 attacks 0
Attacker 5 attacks 1
Attacker 6 attacks 0
```

Say you had 3 total targets instead. Change out `totalTargets` and you'd get:

```
Attacker 0 attacks 0
Attacker 1 attacks 1
Attacker 2 attacks 2
Attacker 3 attacks 0
Attacker 4 attacks 1
Attacker 5 attacks 2
Attacker 6 attacks 0
```